How do you reference an output variable from a powershell script in a future task condition?
I am setting a variable in a job step from within Powershell:
  - pwsh: ./myFile.ps1 
  name: myTaskName

  # Inside myFile.ps1
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildScope;isOutput=true]public"

I can access this later in the YAML with:
- script echo $(myTaskName.buildScope)

... but I can't seem to use it in a condition for a future step of the same job.  How would I do this?
So far my best attempt is...
- task: DoSomething
condition: eq(variables.myTaskName.buildScope, 'public')

What's the catch?
Thanks in advance

We can access the variable from a condition on a step/task. You just need to change the variable format in the condition. For more detailed info, you can refer to my answer.


How do you reference an output variable from a powershell script in a future task condition?

I have added FirstJobname.outputs in the condition as shown below:
dependencies.Jobname1.outputs['rithtask.buildScope']
My yaml script:
jobs:
- job: Rithwik_Job1
  displayName: 'Rithwik_Job1'
  steps:
  - pwsh: ./rith.ps1 
    name: rithtask

- job: Rithwik_Job2
  displayName: 'Rithwik_Job2'
  dependsOn: Rithwik_Job1
  condition: eq(dependencies.Rithwik_Job1.outputs['rithtask.buildScope'], 'public')
  steps:
  - script: echo "Hello Rithwik your testScope is public"

rith.ps1:
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildScope;isOutput=true]public"
Output:

Edit:
You can use below script to do the same in one job:
jobs:
- job: Rithwik_Job
  displayName: 'Rithwik_Job'
  steps:
  - pwsh: ./rith.ps1 
    name: rithtask
  - powershell: |
      if ("$(rithtask.buildScope)" -eq "public") {
        echo "Hello Rithwik, buildScope is Public"
      } else {
        echo "Hello Rithwik, rithtask is not public"
        exit 0        }
    displayName: 'Run PowerShell script'

  - script: echo "Continue with your others steps and operations Rithwik"
    displayName: 'Hello Rithwik Echo'

Output:

And:


Thankyou, that works fine if you have two jobs.  It's not possible to do it all inside 1 job (condition on a task)?  I have a lot of build artifacts and keen to not have to copy them to the pipeline

Wherever you want to use the output of it, use with that job pipeline

@RithwikBojja I was looking to add a condition to a task / step in the same job.  This doesn't seem possible?

I have edited the answer @mct2386, to do it in one job.

Thanks @RithwikBojja, it doesn't seem possible to access the variable from a condition on a step/task?  As opposed to in another Powershell.
I wanted to use the variable to decide whether to run a step later in the same job.

Why cant you use if condition?

for the second part I am not using powershell, i’m conditionally using a task.  I’m only using powershell for the first step because you can’t use regex in conditions

Based on your requirement, you need to use the output variable from previous task to the condition of the next tasks.
This is achievable.
To meet your requirement, you need to change the variable format in the condition.
From
condition: eq(variables.myTaskName.buildScope, 'public') 

To
condition: eq(variables['myTaskName.buildScope'], 'public')

Here is an example:
steps:
- pwsh: ./myFile.ps1 
  name: myTaskName

- script:  echo "test"
  condition: eq(variables['myTaskName.buildScope'], 'public')

Result:

